# How to index the missing x for each row

Tags: r

Suppose we have the following data set:

```
x1   x2   x3
1    NA   3
NA   1   1
3    NA  NA
```

Then for each missing x index it with `j` for each row `i`, for example `x2` in the first row and second column, so `w12` is calculated to fill the missing `x12` and so on.. The weight is calculated by using the following formula:

```
w[i][j] = 1 / 1 + exp(-x[j]) * beta_{o}
```

How can I code this in r?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show the desired output based on the sample input? Do you want just the weights in their own object, or do you want to fill the missing values with those weights? What is `beta_{o}`? If we take `x[3, 3]` as an example, why isn't there an `i` or some sort of aggregate (mean? sum? prod?) in the weight function? As written, `1/1+exp(-x[j])*beta_{o}` for the 3rd column would return 2 values - one for each of the non-missing 3rd column values. So which one goes in the `w[3, 3]`?

Comment: `missing <- which(is.na(dataset), arr.ind=TRUE)` will give you a matrix with the row and column positions of each missing value. As @GregorThomas points out, it is unclear how you want to use that information.

Comment: i want to fill the missing x with the weight

Comment: Bur your formula for weight computes a weight for every filled value per column. So the number of weights != the number of filled values.

Comment: no, it will index x by j only if it is missing